# Video continuously pausing when home streamed to iPhone with Bluetooth headphones

Tags: itunes, bluetooth, iphone, streaming, home-sharing

I have my itunes library on home sharing to share my movie collection across my devices so I can watch either on my iPhone or apple tv. Streaming to my apple tv is perfect but streaming to my iPhone is buggy. I recently bought a new pair of blue tooth headphones to get rid the wires and they work great for listeing to music on home streaming but when I try stream movies from my pc to my iPhone using my headphones the video will play for +- 30 seconds, then pause and wait for what feels like minutes on end. Then it will play again for 30 seconds and pause. It seemed like a streaming issue but if I plug in the supplied cable for the headphones and don't use the bluetooth it streams fine for most movies. If it's a long movie(2.5hrs+) that is large file then even that will battle to stream to my iphone with bluetooth off. TV series episodes stream fine with no hesitation.

I have searched the net for answers but nothing comes up relating specifically to my issue or anyway to solve it. I have reset modem, phone, pc logged in and out of home sharing, nothing seems to fix the issue.

Putting the movies on my phone is also not an option because I don't have the space available even if I took all the apps and data off I would have enough space for maybe 1 or 2 movies. I only have a 16gb iPhone 5C

All streaming is from windows 7 PC with iTunes 12. I have tried 2 different routers thinking that maybe the issue but also no luck

I hope someone can come back with an answer

**EDIT 2015-01-21**

So after some more testing with different videos it seems the issue is a large bitrate file of 19000Kbps+ will not stream to my iphone if my bluetooth headphones are connected. The other videos I have now are all around 10000Kbps range and they work. I cannot confirm what is the max Kbps rate at which streaming and bluetooth headphones will not work but 19000kbps is too large.

Also My router doesn't have the ability to switch wifi to 5Ghz so I can't confirm if this would stop the "interference" between the headphones and wifi signal.

I'll update in a few days with more findings after I do some more testing.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that the bluetooth (and other nearby wireless devices) work on the 2.4GHz band and thus interfering with the wifi data causing streaming issues. That would also indicate why it works better without the bluetooth headphones.

Comment: Looking into the possibility now. Still seems odd though. If the interference existed wouldn't it cause me to have issues watching youtube, streaming podcasts and just generally connecting over wifi?

Comment: To some degree yes, but if the youtube/podcasts are of low quality (compared to movies) then they will also need less amount of data to be streamed and so perhaps it doesnt need to stop and "buffer" to catch up.

Comment: Could the bitrate on the files be too high? The file I'm testing with has a Kbps of 19075? I tried another file with a bitrate of 9775 and it's playing fine. It's hasn't paused once.

Answer (score 0):

If your Wi-Fi is 2.5 GHz, it will be susceptible to interference from Bluetooth headphones, which use the same band. I had the same issue that was fixed on my iPad, which is capable of connecting to 5 GHz Wi-Fi. If your device does not have a chip capable of recognizing the 5 GHz Wi-Fi, it appears there is not much you can do. My LG phone still has same issue. Oddly enough, I had been using Bluetooth headphones for months, then last week this buffering problem began. Perhaps it's the influx of wireless devices that were undoubtedly purchased over the holiday that are causing more interference on the 2.5 GHz than was occurring prior to that. I have reverted to wired headphones for all my 2.5 GHz devices and there is not even a hint of the aforementioned issue.